# Hierarchy of AWS resources?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Is there a general guide, documentation or a book that explains to me the hierarchical structure of AWS resources (ie. regions contain VPCs, VPCs contain EC2 instances and subnets, etc). Is there such a thing / source?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/what-is-amazon-vpc.html; the first image on that page shows precisely the hierarchy you describe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @ceejayoz pointed out, [What is Amazon VPC? - Amazon Virtual Private Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/what-is-amazon-vpc.html) shows this diagram:

[image]

The diagram specifically refers to **resources that connect to a VPC**, which you can think of as a traditional network. Any services that 'launch' resources (eg Amazon EC2, Amazon RDS) will put them in a VPC and in a specific subnet, which maps to an Availability Zone. Think of it as assigning specific resources in an AWS data center, so it lives in just one AZ.

However, SaaS-type services (eg Amazon S3, Amazon DynamoDB, Amazon SQS) operate outside of VPCs and are 'always on'. They are **regional services** that replicate across multiple Availability Zones but you don't need to specify where they go since AWS manages them for you. Think of it like Gmail, which is 'always on'.

I use this mental model:

- A **subnet** is a logical construct in a specific Availability Zone (AZ)
- An **Availability Zone** is a Data Center (sometimes multiple Data Centers) where actual computers run
- A **Region** is a collection of AZs and also includes AWS-run services like Amazon S3